Django migrations operations inside RunPython code
I'm working with data migrations in django, and at some point, I'll have to run migrations.RunPython. The point is that I wish I could execute migrations operations(AddField, AlterField) under certain conditions.
For example:
def forward_migration(apps, schema_editor):
    if some_condition:
       migrations.AddField(...)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('some_app', '0002_auto_...'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forward_migration)


Thanks in advance.

I see no reason why you would want to do this, and I also see no question being asked here. Please clarify.

I want to add a ForeingKey to a django class with null=True if that class has records in the database, and with null=False otherwise
